# MySQL Dump on Ubuntu 20.04 returns 0 byte file and runs indefinitely. Works on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am using identical configs on Ubuntu 20.04 as I was previously on 18.04; however, on 20.04 the CPU shoots up to 50% usage and the process runs indefinitely, and by indefinitely I mean it was running for over 24hr when I caught the issue. I am completely stumped on why this is not working on 20.04. Mysqldump is installed using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends mysql-client
```

Output of `mysqldump -V` Ubuntu 20.04:

```
mysqldump  Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

Output of `mysqldump -V` Ubuntu 18.04:

```
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.36, for Linux (x86_64)
```

Terminal command:

```
sudo mysqldump --defaults-file=/var/mysqldump/conf.cfg test_db | gzip > /var/tmp/backup.gz
```

Contents of conf.cfg:

```
[client]
host=xxx
user=xxx@db
password=xxx

[mysqldump]
quick
single-transaction
skip-lock-tables
```

Why would this work on Ubuntu 18.04, but fails indefinitely while consuming CPU resources on 20.04? Is there a settings change on 20.04 that I have overlooked?

Comment: Are there 2 CPU cores?

Comment: Look carefully at `top` (or `htop`)-- see if `gzip` is the one hogging the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a bug with 8.0.27: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105288